# Need permission for Windows client to access linux NFS

Tags: filesystems, windows, nfs

I have a linux NFS the /etc/exports is like below:

```
/opt/nfs 10.8.0.0/20(no_root_squash, rw, sync)
```

I can r/w files from other linux machines. However, I only have read permission on Windows client.

What I did on the Windows Server 2012 R2 box is installing 'Services for NFS' and use following command to mount it. Can somebody point out what is wrong?

Thanks!

```
mount \\10.8.0.2\opt\nfs X:
```

EDIT:
  I have tried to use `mount -u:user -p:password \\...` with a user I created identical both on linux and windows side, still doesn't work. Here is the Windows message:
 You need permission to perform this action
 You require permission from S-1-1-0 to make changes to this file

Comment: What does the log file on the server say when you mount the share from Windows?

Comment: where can I found this log?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Windows issue. (The asker has already confirmed the NFS share works fine from other Linux/Unix based client systems.)

Comment: You probably need to [specify a user account](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/windows/storage-file-systems/connect-windows-server-2012-r2-nfs-shares/) to associate with the [mount point](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754350.aspx). Otherwise you'll end up accessing the share as "nobody".

Comment: I've tried that, with/without having same user/password on both side. Still get access denied. Windows said user (with some user ID) access is denied.

Comment: If you create a world-writable directory on the server, can you then *create* a file in that directory from your Windows client? If so, who owns the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick I found to set the default UID and GID of the Windows client to match the UID and GID of the nfs share. Here is a  link to the full article [Windows 7: Client for NFS and User Name Mapping without AD, SUA](https://support.dbssolutions.com/support/solutions/articles/1649-windows-7-client-for-nfs-and-user-name-mapping-without-ad-sua)  and here are the basic steps.

1) Run `regedit` on the Windows machine and locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default`

2) Add two DWORD values: `AnonymousUid` and `AnonymousGid`

3) Set these values to the UID and GID of the owner of the shared linux directory.

4) Restart the Client for NFS service or reboot the computer.

`*.reg` file example for quick adding:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default]
"AnonymousUid"=dword:000003e8
"AnonymousGid"=dword:000003e8
```

Comment: Sounds like `mount -o anon ...`

Comment: I thought the part about setting the user and group ID of the anonymous user to match the Linux share might be the trick to getting r/w permission.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thanks! Also, I tried to put all_squash,anonuid,anongid trick. That also works.

Comment: @Archer, do you have particular content of your file? It still doesn't work in this way for me.